# Python: In list of tuples, retrieve previous tuple's key when next tuple's value is found?

Tags: python, list, tuples, key

I have a list of tuples:

```
sentenceParts = [('there', 'EX'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('huge', 'JJ'), ('shaggy', 'NN'), ('dog', 'NN'), ('in', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('yard', 'NN')]
```

I wish to have a function whereby if, for example, I know I need to find the value 'IN' (whose key is, in this case 'in'), the function will return the PREVIOUS tuples key (in this example, 'dog') as well as that tuple's key's numerical index (in this case I believe it would be 5[0])

I currently get the value to search on ('in') from this line:

```
wordIndex = next((word for word, value in sentenceParts if value == "IN"), None)
```

That line returns the key of 'in', correctly.  I need a similar way to obtain the output I need ('dog',5[0] prehaps).  I've tried messing with various versions of sentenceParts.index(wordIndex) but I'm definitely not using it right.  I've found at least three different ways to get the code to return 'in' to me, and a few dozen ways to get a ValueError or AttributeError... but no luck yet with wrapping my head around it returning something like 'dog', 5[0]

If I had to put it into pseudo-code it would be:

```
wordIndex = next((PREVIOUS word, INDEX, for word, value in sentenceParts if value == "IN"), None)
```

Thanks.  Apologies if this has been asked before but I can't find anything that actually fits the bill after significant searching...  and if I did see it, I may not have been knowledgeable enough to recognize it.  Hopefully I didn't just miss it.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: This is some interesting NLP work you're doing! ;). Congratulations on a well-crafted question

Comment: What should be the result when search 'EX'?

Comment: Well, given what I'm doing before-hand, I would never have a search for 'EX', however, should the first word be an 'IN', it should return 'none' so that I could use an alternate method to adjust the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip` and `enumerate` over zipped lists:

```
def get_previous_item(lst, search_item):
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(lst, lst[1:])):
        if y[1] == search_item:
            return i, x[0]
```

**Usage**:

```
>>> get_previous_item(sentenceParts, 'IN')
(5, 'dog')
```

Comment: This works great and since it's already set up as a function saves me a step.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to iterate over digrams, not single words, so you always have the preceding word as available context:

```
words = [('there', 'EX'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('huge', 'JJ'), ('shaggy', 'NN'), ('dog', 'NN'), ('in', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('yard', 'NN')]
next(((token1, i)
      for i, ((token1, pos1), (token2, pos2))
      in enumerate(zip(words, words[1:]))
      if pos2 == 'IN'
     ), None)
# => ('dog', 5)
```

Comment: Thank you.  This adds to my understanding, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
[(sentenceParts[i-1][0], i-1) for i, (w,t) in enumerate(sentenceParts) if t == 'IN' and i >0]


[('dog', 5)]
```

Comment: Thank you, very much in keeping with my original attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Something more straightforward, which returns `None` if no previous key can be found (if either the key being searched for isn't found or is in the first position):

```
def find_prev( lst, key ):
    try:
        i = [x[1] for x in lst].index(key)
        if i > 0:
            return (i-1,lst[i-1][0])
    except:
        pass
    return None
```

Comment: Functions implicitly return a `None`, so you can skip `return None`. (I know you know :)).

Comment: Probably, you cannot prefer this one: `i = [x[0] for x in lst].index(key)`. Shouldn't it be `x[1]` ?

Comment: @scott Thanks all!